# Spring Boot +thymeleaf форма с чекбоксами

Tags: checkbox

Привет, воюю с thymeleaf , хочу сделать следующее: в таблицу выводятся данные, в конце каждой строки есть чекбокс, можно выделить несколько чекбоксов, по нажатии на кнопку "сохранить" данные отправляются в контроллер где уже производятся манипуляции по сохранению. Собственно вопрос как отправить массив данных с формы которые отмечены чекбоксами ?

Answer (score 1):

Решил следующим образом:
Вспомогательный класс в который сохраняются индексы выбранных чекбоксов:

```
public class Foo {
    private List<String> checkedItems;

    public List<String> getCheckedItems() {
        return checkedItems;
    }

    public void setCheckedItems(List<String> checkedItems) {
        this.checkedItems = checkedItems;
    }
}
```

Получение индексов и обработка их в контроллере

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/processForm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute(value="foo") Foo foo) {
        // Get value of checked item.

        List<String> checkedItems = foo.getCheckedItems();
        for(String s : checkedItems) {

        }
            return "redirect:/main";
    }
```

Код страницы:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/processForm}" th:object="${foo}" method="post"><tr th:each="group, iterStat : ${groups}" th:id="'group-' + ${group.id}" >
                        <td th:text="${iterStat.count}"><a href="/groups/${group.id}">№</a></td>
                        <td th:text="${group.id}">Screen name</td>
                        <td th:text="${group.screen_name}">Screen name</td>
                        <td th:text="${group.name}">Group name</td>
                        <td th:text="${group.members_count}">members_count</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${iterStat.count}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                        <input type="submit" text="Add checked" />
                    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public String method(@RequestParam(name = "box") int[] box) {

}
```